# Using "is" in this question with plural noun?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, plural-forms

Can someone explain why we use "is" in this question:

> What is going to happen to global temperatures in the next 50 years?

Is it because we are collectively thinking about temperatures as a whole? Or because of the verb "happen"? Why would we not use "are"

I'm a native speaker but I'm confused with the rules of this question.

Comment: You say "Who's there?" even when you know it's probably your entire office at the door.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject of the verb is *what*, which is singular even though it may imply a number of possibilities.

If *temperatures* was the subject, we could say 'Are temperatures going to rise?'